# What is the meaning of the Jerry Maguire reference in "Begin Again"?

Tags: plot-explanation, reference, begin-again, jerry-maguire

In [*Begin Again*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1980929/), Saul uses a Jerry Maguire reference on Dan here:

[image]

> Saul: Don't bother her. Don't bother her. It's not **Jerry Maguire**.

What is the meaning of the Jerry Maguire reference in "Begin Again"?

Comment: Some context here would be useful. In what circumstances was this said?

Comment: You don't need to create different account for different question, keeping single account will help you handle things better, Refer [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to know how to merge multiple accounts.

Answer (score -1):

Jerry Maguire, was a slick sports agent, however he has a crisis of conscience, he pens a heartfelt company-wide memo that promptly gets him fired. The Reference in Begin Again, simply is stating that there is no need to bother said person as she has not got a crisis of Conscience.
Hope this helps.